# Is MP4 a valid or common container for ProRes?

Tags: codec, mp4, prores

Is MP4 a valid or common container for ProRes? I've only seen it in MOVs and MXFs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, officially, ProRes is not a [registered codec](http://mp4ra.org/#/codecs) for the ISOBMFF family, of which MP4 is a member.